# Reset "remember me" cookie for all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

On my rails app I would like to force all users to sign-in when they next visit the site, rather than being remembered. I understand that I have to delete a cookie but which one and how do I do this?

I'm using rails 3.2 and devise 2.2.1.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use devises `sign_out` function, and build a private method in your application controller that forces it when a request is made. In your `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :force_sign_out!


  private # avoid interference

  def force_sign_out!
    if user_signed_in?
       sign_out(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

You could even run a block on your `before_filter`

```
before_filter do
  if # conditions
    force_sign_out!
  end
end
```

hope this helps!

-Brian

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for. However, won't this sign-out every user every time they visit the site? I just want to do it once and then return to normal.

Comment: I added a condition to check whether the user's last sign in was at a time before a specific date, which is what I want :)

Comment: Nice! Ya this came in handy when I had to suthenticated models and I had to verify that no two users were signed in at the same time as different types.